# Symfony2 Security and ACL for category

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I am building an application logic with symfony2 that requires some form of secuirty.

Application logic:

There are "Translations", and "Languages" table some users, should be allowed to edit certain parts of the "Translations" table for example. User1 can edit translations that are in French (fr category). Other user can edit translations that are in Spanish etc... And some user might be edit both of those translations. I also need to make some users to be able assign those "Translations" to other users.

So I guess the most suitable way to achieve this would be ACL system. But there's one thing that is worrying me, there will be a lot of translations - hundreds of thousands, so if I assign ACL to each user and each translation, the ACL table grows really large, what I would like to do is assign category(Language from Language table) instead of translation, so that certain user would be able to edit all translations with assigned category (en, fr, es ... etc..). How could I achieve something like this?

I think I can't get away without ACL, but I think it's not enough, maybe combination of ACL and voters? But I don't how to put everything together.

Comment: You don't worry. ACL will take care about this one. But you need to add proper role to translations or languages while creating those records. ACL will give permissions based on the role

Comment: What do you mean by "ACL will take care about this one"? Also I need dynamically change whose allowed and not, I am not sure if proper way to add and remove roles so often?

Comment: Please check this one http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html . This have the proper explanation with roles and permissions